# Error processing a knockout computed when loading with requireJS

Tags: knockout.js

I am using KnockoutJS 2.2 and attempting to implement app navigation by setting the "currentPanel" to display on the main template page

```
<div id="content" data-bind="template: {name: currentPanel}"></div>
```

and so changing the panel name in the router then will change the displayed content

```
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes : {
     "" : "home",
     "index.html" : "home"
  },

  home : function() {
     app.appModel.set({'panelName' : 'index-template'});
  },
```

The model behind this looks like

```
app.appModel = new Backbone.Model({
   panelName : 'index-template'
});

// VERSION 3: Using a simple JS object
app.AppViewModel = function(model){
  this.panelName = kb.observable(model, 'panelName');

  this.currentPanel = ko.computed(function() {
     return this.panelName();
  }, this);
}
app.appViewModel = new app.AppViewModel(app.appModel);
ko.applyBindings(app.appViewModel, $('#content')[0]);
```

This works very nicely when not loading with requireJS.

However - when I load my scripts using require

```
require.config({
  paths : {
     jquery : 'vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min',
     underscore : 'vendor/underscore',
     backbone : 'vendor/backbone',
     knockout : 'vendor/knockout-2.2.0.debug',
     knockback : 'vendor/knockback-0.17-2'
  }
});

define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'knockout', 'knockback'], function($, _, Backbone, ko, kb){

 // my code here....
});
```

using the AMD versions of underscore and backbone [from here][1], and to my understanding [knockoutJS is AMD Ready™][2].

**I get this JS error** that occurs on definition of the 'this.currentPanel' ko.computed field:

```
Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.
```

(For some reason my Firebug does not even show me the knockout.js library under the Script pane for debugging - it is loading under Net - which was not my experience when using requireJS as integrated into Dojo, but maybe it's my version of Firebug on Linux).

I've also tried Knockout 2.2.1 with jQuery 1.9 (2.2.0 is incompatible with jQuery 1.9, hence the change there).

From what I can tell from the knockoutJS code, the declaration of ko.computed defaults as read-only, which I tried to combat with a read_only=false attribute; but that did not seem to help, and I could not figure out how to tell KO that it is writable.

But, since this error does not appear in a non-requireJS loading situation, I think I am chasing the wrong thing.

Can anyone make sense of the error in this context?  Am I facing some configuration issue or an honest KnockoutJS issue?

--- Update ---

There is a Knockback observable in the original definition, but if I remove it and simply use a ko.observable, like

```
// VERSION 3: Using a simple JS object
app.AppViewModel = function(model){

  this.currentPanel = ko.computed(function() {
     return 'index-template';
  }, this);
}
app.appViewModel = new app.AppViewModel(app.appModel);
ko.applyBindings(app.appViewModel, $('#content')[0]);
```

the exact error remains.

```
Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.
```

Comment: this is not a typo is it? "kb" instead of "ko" ??? this.panelName = kb.observable(model, 'panelName');

Comment: `kb` is for [Knockback](http://kmalakoff.github.io/knockback/). I think this error is coming from Knockback. Perhaps you can get help from the developer.

Comment: correct, kb is Knockback - I updated the question to show that the problem still exists after eliminating use of Knockback. The problem is that I cannot debug this due to the way requireJS is loading my scripts.  Every page load only shows require.js and one other script - jquery, underscore, or knockout, seemingly randomly selected, in the Firebug Scripts panel.  Same effect in Chrome.  Even if Knockout does show up and I set a breakpoint, it is not respected next time it shows up in the scripts pane. I cannot even use 'debugger' to stop execution where the error is thrown. Ugh.